# Changing text and image with arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a simple way to make the text and image change when clicking a back/forward arrow?

I do not know if it is better to make everything change on click or to make a div go on top of the other on click, I would appreciate a example for one transition so I can add more myself.

```css
#hi h1 {
  margin-top: 5%;
  color: white;
}

#hi h2 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#hi h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

#hi {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hi">
  <h1> basics </h1>
  <h2> Text </h2>
  <h3> Another text </h3>
  <h3>
    <img src="images/image1.png" alt="Image" height="42" width="42"> 
  </h3>
</div>
```

Comment: `back` or `forward` arrow ?  you are talking about the one on top left of the browser?

Comment: I think Lisa is talking about a gallery left/right button to flick through images/captions. But those buttons aren't in the HTML of the question, so who knows.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you don't have too many pictures, wrap each within a container `<div class='hidden ...'>` and add them to your HTML. You then add event listeners `document.addEventListener('keydown', ...)` listening for arrow keys and toggle the hidden class via `div.classList.toggle('hidden')`. Of course, you need to add a CSS rule `.hidden { display: none; }`.

Comment: There are a **lot** of good carousel libraries out there. Why not try one of those instead of reinventing the wheel? I would recommend owlcarousel https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/

Comment: Why don't you learn the basics of Javascript first?

Comment: I just need two arrows on the sides of the div and when you click the right arrow, the text changes and the image as well and when you click the left one it goes back to how it was

Comment: "just this" is not that easy. It's called a carousel and requires basic understanding of how JS and CSS work. And/or you can use one of the zillion carousel plugins/libraries out there.